# Preventing macOS installers from disappearing from the boot drive

Tags: macos, install

Until recently, I've kept installers for several different versions of macOS in my Application folder to create bootable installer disks. Lately I've noticed that they just seem to disappear. I'm guessing they're being "helpfully" removed after updates happen.

I've tried locking the top folders of the installer apps, but this just results in empty folders being retained. I could lock all the subfolders, but I suspect that might break something. I keep copies of the installers on an external drive which is usually disconnected, so that works, but it would be more convenient to keep them on my boot drive and it's a little spooky to find them gone.

Any ideas on preventing macOS installers from disappearing from the boot drive?

Comment: I've always dragged a copy to the desktop (Option-Drag) from the Applications folder. Then once you have run the installer and rebooted you can place your copy on the desktop back in the Applications folder or wherever you store such things. Nope it's not elegant or automatic but it is simple.

Comment: Unfortunately I've restored the backups from the external drive to the Applications folder many times, but they just keep disappearing. To clarify, I'm not running the installers on this Mac, just running the createinstallmedia command to create bootable installer disks.

Comment: I just keep them on another drive [though just another partition would do at a push]. One you've copied [or moved] Finder loses track of it so it's safe. I have every OS back to Lion that way.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround might be to [create a disk image](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/create-a-disk-image-dskutl11888/mac) on the boot drive, mount the image, copy the macOS installers there, unmount the image and then lock the disk image. This would provide easy access and should prevent disappearance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I also made this experience and I would not try to mess with System permissions or ACL in a vital folder like /Applications.

My answer might be off-topic but I want to help out to re-download the lost macOS installers in an easy way.
I keep those installers off the default boot volumes' Application folder for that reason, like on a second drive in my 3.1 MacPro.

It is inconvenient, but currently the only way besides that great idea from lava37 with a protected disc image above.
Another trick can be to just keep in a folder in your home directory and to just drag'n drop them to the Application folder whenever needed.

**In case you lost the macOS installers:**

*If you want to re-download any macOS Installer* you may need without searching too much on Apples' webpages *and you are not afraid of the command-line*, you can use this fantastic toolkit here. I use it for the creation of macOS USB sticks as for the dosdude1 or pike tools for my officially unsupported MacPro.

[gibMacOS - Py2/py3 script that can download macOS components direct from Apple](https://github.com/corpnewt/gibMacOS)

From the description:
"[...] Py2/py3 script that can download macOS components direct from Apple

Can also now build Internet Recovery USB installers from Windows using dd and 7zip.[...]"